# Synchronizing method or entire queue?

Tags: java, synchronization

If a queue is to be accessed by several threads, but it's currently only being modified by a single method `getNextInQueue()`, what's the most appropriate form of synchronizing access to the queue?

Currently, I declared the queue as a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, but I don't want to reach a deadlock where multiple threads are waiting for a lock to be released. Another way I can handle this is by not synchronizing the queue, but synchronizing `getNextInQueue()`. However, as this code is used in the future, I don't think this will scale as well. (Every programmer that makes modifications to the queue will have to ensure that she synchronizes the operation.)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest, and most correct way is use the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.  I do not believe this would cause a deadlock, however.  The one thing I am not sure of, however, is how the Concurrent wrappers handle situations where you use an iterator.  I seem to remember having to fall back to the old `synchronized` method of wrapping all calls to the underlying collection (reads and writes).  I am pretty sure thats what the Concurrent wrapper is doing, though.

Comment: From the documentation: "Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the queue at some point at or since the creation of the iterator." So if you ever need to work with consistent snapshots, you might as well just use a `LinkedList` with `synchronized`.

Comment: @millimoose Here you're wrong. Trying to change the queue while the iterator is iterating it will result in [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

Comment: Also, near as I can tell (by looking at the source of the backport), `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is not a wrapper around anything. It's a standalone collection implemented without locking all the data.

Comment: @millimoose you should read the content of the [*link*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html): "This exception **may** be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible...Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed... Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs."

Comment: @alfasin Can you produce a test case where `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` will do that?

Comment: @millimoose you mentioned `synchronized LinkedList` not `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. Second, like the manual says - you can't *count* on such an exception to be thrown. The behavior is unpredictable. But it's an interesting question you asked, I didn't try to implement such an exception. I'll look into it tomorrow, it's too late now ;)

Comment: @alfasin You misread my first comment then. The documentation quote was referring to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in the answer.

Comment: @alfasin Also: the javadoc for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` says it won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The javadoc for the iterator `ConcurrentLinkedQueue#iterator()` (`ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Itr`) says it will never throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. At no point in the entire source code of the iterator is a `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown. The behaviour is *not* unpredictable, and you can, in fact, rely on it *not ever* being thrown. (For `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and possibly some of the other `java.util.concurrent` collections.)

Comment: @millimoose in that case we agree :). btw, just checked and it's very easy to make such an exception to be thrown when you work with `LinkedList`

Answer (score 3):

If it's a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, and the queue state is only data shared between threads, you don't need to synchronize anything. That's the whole point of using a concurrent collection. A producer-consumer setup shouldn't deadlock unless you're doing something strange. (Like having the same thread be a producer and consumer.)

Answer (score 2):

synchronizing only `getNext()` will not be a good idea - if you want to do that, you'll have to synchronize the `insert` as well. 
**Example:** 
If there are no elements in the queue and thread A tries to `getNext()` and doesn't finished executing the method - a new item could be inserted to the queue by thread B, which will result in thread A pending  on the queue even though there is a new item in it.

**To sum up**:
If concorency is important, I would stay with `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`

Comment: -1: This is not true for the `java.util.concurrent` collections.

Comment: @millimoose I was referring to his thought about "Another way I can handle this is by not synchronizing the queue". I think you'll agree with me that using an un-synchronized queue and implementing synchronization only for the `getter` might result in a dead-lock.

Comment: Hm, I think I get it now, I guess that sentence could be interpreted as "using an unsynchronised collection type". (Hard to tell without any code in the question.) Sorry.